# Is my prayer valid even though I mispronounced a word?

Tags: salat, sajda, fajr, pronunciation

When I was reading the Fajr prayer, I was trying to say it quickly because it was late and I was reciting it out loud. When I did sajda (prostration), I think there was too much saliva in my mouth or something so what I said sounded like "subhanarabial'aya" instead of "subhanarabial'ala." It was only one time though. Do you know if my prayer is acceptable? Or have I changed the meaning of the word?

Comment: Mistakes happen by anyone, and it was an accident and you did not purposely mispronounced it, all the prayers and duas which we ask from our Lord is accepted by Allah Subhaana wa Ta'ala himself. Only he knows (or accepts) your prayers, whether it is accepted or not. So don't  be anxious about it he is The Most Gracious and Most Merciful.

Answer (score 1):

```
                 In the name of Allah, the most Gracious, the most merciful
```

First of all, I should mention that on the whole, Sajdeh (prostration) can be considered from different aspects, and one of those aspects is related to “pronunciation” as you mentioned.

As a general Islamic rule of Salah (prayer), there are some conditions which can invalidate your Salah (prayer). One of them is relevant to the issue of Pronounciation. In other word, it is said that in case that your pronunciation is not true (which changes the meaning), as a consequence it would invalidate your Salah or Namaz.

In the above-mentioned example as you gave, i.e.:

> "subhanarabial'aya" instead of "subhanarabial'ala."

Seemingly it has changed its true meaning. Since actually the letter “P” is not available in Arabic language, then it shows that apparently it has changed the meaning to the best of my knowledge.

But, may be mis-pronunciation in Mustahab parts of Salah such as Qunoot doesn't invalidate that.

And Allah knows best

---

**References:**

- [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir)
- [farsi.khamenei.ir](http://farsi.khamenei.ir)
- [sallatt.loxblog.com](http://sallatt.loxblog.com)

Answer (score 0):

Mis-pronunciation does invalidate the salat only in these four places:

1. When saying Allah Akbar to begin the salat
2. When saying essalamou alyakom to finish the salat
3. Al Fatiha
4. When saying the two testimonies just before finishing the salat

For all other acts, mis-pronunciation does not invalidate the salat

And Allah knows best

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider elaborating your answer by adding refernces to support your claim. I strongly recommend you to take the [tour], check our [help] and read [answer] to learn more about the site.